# How to send authentication parameters in PUT request - Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, put

Trying to perform a load testing using Jmeter tool however can not pass authentication. 
The following curl works well

```
curl -u <USERNAME>:<PASSWORD> -X PUT "http://server-url/artifactory/my-repository/my/new/artifact/directory/file.txt" -T Desktop/myNewFile.txt
```

I need to upload file via PUT method based on the curl sample above and can not do it because do not understand where username and password values should be placed in the HTTP Request sampler, in the parameters part, Post Body or somewhere else.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a [HTTP Authorisation Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) to your Test Plan and configure it as follows:

- Base URL: `http://server-url`
- Username: `USERNAME`
- Password: `PASSWORD`

JMeter will generate relevant [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header and add it to the request. See [How to Use HTTP Basic Authentication in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) article for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing, but you probably add the HTTP header

```
Authentication: basic [base64 of username:password]
```

Google "HTTP Basic Authentication"